# How to use for loop in cplex library?

Tags: python, cplex

I would like to run several input parameter for r2 in total_r2 by using CPLEX library.
I use numpy and pandas library in pycharm.
However, I could not get the final result (obj_lambda) for each input parameter.

```
import cplex
from docplex.mp.model import Model
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mdl = Model(name='Scheduling')
inf = cplex.infinity
bigM= 10000

Total_P = 11 # number of places
Total_T = 8 # number of transitions

AT_temp = AT.transpose()

total_r2 = 5

storage_PS_one = []
storage_PS_two = []
storage_PS_three = []
storage_lambda = []


#Define the place without conflict place
CP = np.count_nonzero(AT, axis=1, keepdims=True) #calculate the nonzero elements for each row
P_conflict = []
P_zero = []

for a in range(0, len(CP)):
    if CP[a].item(0) > 2:
        P_conflict.append(places[a])
    else:
        P_zero.append(places[a])



print(df_final)
print('storage_lambda', storage_lambda)
```

Answer (score 1):

See [montecarlo example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoomontecarlooptimization.py)

```
import random
import math

random.seed(1)

from docplex.mp.model import Model

# original model

nbKids=300
mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
costBus40=500.0;
costBus30=400.0;
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= nbKids, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*costBus40 + nbbus30*costBus30)

nbSamples=20
nbMaxKidsAbsent=30;

nbKidsLess=[random.randint(0,nbMaxKidsAbsent) for i in range(0,nbSamples)]
nbKidsOptions=[nbKids-nbKidsLess[i] for i in range(0,nbSamples)]

#Monte Carlo optimization

totalCost=0.0;
for i in range(0,nbSamples):
    
   mdl.get_constraint_by_name("kids").rhs=nbKidsOptions[i]
   mdl.solve()
   cost=mdl.solution.get_objective_value()
   totalCost+=cost
   print("if we need to bring ",nbKidsOptions[i]," kids  to the zoo");
   print("cost = ",cost)

print()   
averageCost=1/nbSamples*totalCost


print("------------------------------");
print("average cost = ",math.ceil(averageCost));
```